# column index out of range Groovy Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy, soapui

I have the below code which is giving me a `The column index is out of range:1, number of columns 0`

```
def Column = resXml.DBRange.db*.text()
def Points = resXml.DBRange.points*.text()
//sorting it all out into a multidimensional array (index per index)
bigList = [Column, Points].transpose()

//iterating through the array
bigList.each
{//creating two smaller lists and making it readable for sql part later
    def column = it[0]
    def points = it[1]
    //further splitting the points to test each
    pointList = points.split(" ")
    pointList.each
    {//test each points range per column
        def sqlResult = sql.rows "select * from my_table where ${column} <> ",[it]
            log.info sqlResult
    }
}
sql.close();
return;
```

I don't understand because when i say `log.info it` (and comment out the SQL)instead of `log.info sqlResult` i get back all the column names

Comment: please correlate the error with a line in your code.  and shouldnt your sql there have some `:tocompareto` ?

Comment: Not sure that `def sqlResult = sql.rows "select * from my_table where ${column} <> ",[it]` is valid SQL?

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. I changed the end of that SQL to be `where ${column} <> '${it}'"` sigh i feel real daft over that